# Are you required to use the alias when referencing a table after aliasing?

Tags: sql

I've been using DataCamp to learn SQL. The first statement returned correct but the second returned incorrect. I'm having a hard time understanding why the second is incorrect since the aliasing should make them equivalents.

**Statement 1**

`SELECT c.name AS city, l.name AS language FROM cities AS c CROSS JOIN languages AS l`

**Statement 2**

`SELECT cities.name AS city, languages.name AS language FROM cities AS c CROSS JOIN languages AS l`

Comment: It would be helpful, if you explain what actually happens when you run the second statement, was there an error message?

Comment: Yeah, `ALIAS` is somewhat misleading as SQL keyword. It does not add a name *alternative*, but *replaces* the name going forward. Something like `THIS_INSTANCE_FROM_HERE_ON_OUT_ONLY_REFERRED_TO_AS` might be a wee bit unwieldy, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, table alias renames the table in the context of the query, making the original name inaccessible.

For example, from PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html):

> The alias becomes the new name of the table
> reference so far as the current query is
> concerned — it is not allowed to refer to the
> table by the original name elsewhere in the query.

Answer (score 1):

An alias totally replaces the name of the table.  There is only once arcane case that I can think of where this isn't true (`update` statements in SQL Server).

Why?  The answer is simple.  Aliases are really needed when the same table appears in the `FROM` clause multiple times.  For instance, if your query were:

```
SELECT cities.name AS city
FROM cities AS c CROSS JOIN 
     cities AS c2
```

Which `cities` would the `SELECT` refer to?  (Ignore for now that this is a useless query!)

A different way of thinking about this is that all table references in the `FROM` clause have an alias.  When you leave it out, the default alias is the table name.  So:

```
FROM cities
```

is defaulted to:

```
FROM cities as cities
```

When you add your own alias, you are replacing the default.